# Understanding trained neural network memory usage

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, gpu, keras

## Background

I have a single layer, 256 hidden-unit, RNN that I've trained with Keras and that I now want to deploy. Ideally, I would like to deploy multiple instances of this RNN onto a GPU. However, at this point, when I load the model with `keras.models.load_model()`, it seems to be using 11Gb of my available 12Gb of GPU memory.

## Questions

1. Why is my network, which is quite small, taking up so much memory? I only want to predict, not train. Am I loading the model the wrong way?
2. Is there some way I can generally understand the mapping of my RNN structure to the amount of GPU memory it will use?
3. Given this understanding, how do I reduce the amount of memory consumed by my RNN?

## Current Understanding

My current estimate of how much memory my network *should* use is given from the number of hyper-parameters:

- 256 input weights
- 256 output weights
- 256x256 recurrent weights
- 256 hidden units
- 256 hidden unit biases

Total: `32 bits/parameter x (4 x 256 + 256 x 256) parameters = 260e6 bits`

This is significantly less then what I'm currently seeing. So my hypothesis is that Keras thinks I'm still training my model and thus is trying to cache batch error sizes. But how else am I supposed to load my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's just a strategy of gpu memory usage. Keras is generally based on tensorflow, and tensorflow default map all your free gpu memory in order to avoid dynamical memory allocation regardless how much memory you will really use.

You can configure it like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3  # or any valid options.
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```